# Yarn 4 and selective dependency resolution not working

Tags: yarn-v4

Is it possible to use selective dependency resolution with Yarn 4? I tried something like this, but when I run yarn the paths in resolution are removed.

This is `npm ls xml2js`.

```
├─┬ @expo/prebuild-config@6.2.6 extraneous
│ └── xml2js@0.6.0 deduped
├─┬ react-native-iap@12.10.7 extraneous
│ ├─┬ @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2 extraneous
│ │ └── xml2js@0.4.23 deduped
│ └── xml2js@0.4.23 extraneous
└── xml2js@0.4.23 extraneous
```

I want to replace `xml2js` in `react-native-iap` with version `0.5.0` and for other libraries keep on `0.6.0`.

I tried something like this, but

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-iap/**/xml2js": "0.6.0",
  },
```

but when I run `yarn` it is deleted from resolutions and nothing changes.

Is it even possible with this version of yarn?